# Using quaternion algebra, determine matrix of reflection given a plane

Tags: matrices, geometry, quaternions, reflection

The question asked us to find the matrix of the reflection on the plane with equation $x+2y-2z=0$. From what I have learnt, the (unit) normal to the plane is $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3}]$. We can treat this as a quaternion, $q=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3},0)$, where $0$ is the real part of the quaternion.

We also learnt that to obtain the matrix of a reflection, the formula is given to be $R(x)=-qxq^{-1}=qxq$.

$$R(x)=qxq=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
    -\frac{2}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\
    -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{2}{3} \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}xq=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
    -\frac{2}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\
    -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{2}{3} \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
    \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\
    \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{2}{3} \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}x$$
The problem comes in when I evaluate the product of matrix. The product is \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{7}{9} & -\frac{4}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & 0\\
    -\frac{4}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{8}{9} & 0\\
    \frac{4}{9} & \frac{8}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
    \end{pmatrix}

Why is the element in the bottom row and column $-1$? My teacher taught us that it should be a positive $1$. Is there something wrong with the formula that I used?

Comment: Well there's at least one sign error in the first matrix. I don't know if it's a copying error.

Comment: I checked. The signs seem correct. Could be because the real part of the quaternion is behind rather than in front.